# Iterative Function Definition to Closed Form

Tags: closed-form, recursion

Is there a general method of turning an iterative function definition, for example $$f(x+1)= x^{f(x-1)}+f(x-1)^x$$ into a closed form equation?  By closed form, I mean that I want an expression that does not grow arbitrarily large in length, and doesn't use symbols like $\sum$ or $\prod$ unless the number of steps for computing them is fixed.  Essentially, it should not take a computer much longer to figure out $f(10000)$ that it should to figure out $f(500)$.

What about solving recursive functions in which $f(x)$ relies on both $f(x+1)$ and $f(x-1)$?  Not necessarily those two, but any inputs both larger and smaller than $x$.

Comment: Wouldn't that be nice! But no, the world does not work to our convenience. If your recursion relation is linear, then there nice procedures. There probably are in a few other special cases. (Definitely are, if one includes not-yet-discovered methods). But a general method? Though I cannot say for sure, I very, very much doubt it. And I can say for sure that your hope to calculate $f(10000)$ without much more work than $f(500)$ is not possible in general. There are calculations which provably have exponential growth no matter what algorithm is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for "Hypergeometric Summation", "Summation in finite terms" and "Symbolic summation".

Read e.g. the chapter "Symbolic Summation" in Bona, Miklos: Handbook of Enumerative Combinatorics. Chapman and Hall/CRC 2015.

There is a theory or an algorithm of Michael Karr:

Karr, Michael: Summation in finite terms. J. Assoc. Comp. Mach. 28 (1981) (2)305-350

[Karr, Michael: Theory of Summation in Finite Terms. J. Symbolic Computation 1 (1985) (3) 303-315](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717185800389)

And there is a theory or an algorithm of Carsten Schneider:

Look for

Schneider Summation

and for

Schneider sums